# Making a 3d text editor in c++

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, opengl

Currently I am looking to write a text editor for linux systems that does some particular text/font highlighting that involves opengl rendering. Does anyone have suggestions for a c++ graphics rendering library that works well with linux (ubuntu in particular for now)?

And advice for where to start with rendering 3d text is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Just to clarify rendering 3d text is a strict requirement of the project.

Comment: You've posted a bounty; so it would seem that you're not yet happy with the answers you've received.  Could you add detail about what you're looking for?

Comment: What I would like to make is a text editor that has syntax highlighting that uses some 3d objects. I'm not just looking for font rendering in opengl although this would be a start. Some of the answers were from a windows perspective, which wasn't the platform I was targeting. Essentially I'd like to find a library that can render 3d text on a variety of different surfaces but if there isn't one I'm hoping to get some tips on where to start with building such a library.

Comment: What do you mean "on a variety of different surfaces"?  Do you want to render the text around a cylinder or sphere?

Comment: @Jcooper, not currently wanting to render on anything other than flat planes for now, but maybe in the future...

Comment: It looks to me like OGLFT and FTGL both do what I think you're asking for at the moment.  Both offer the ability to load a font and create 3d extruded text.  Neither, however, lets you define a path along which to warp the text.  Both allow you to create "text textures" that can be rendered onto arbitrary surfaces, but they're no longer extruded then.

Answer (score 10):

There are basically only three ways to do this at the OpenGL level:

**Raster Fonts.**

Use glBitmap or glDrawPixels to draw a rectangular bunch of pixels onto the screen. The disadvantages of doing this are many: 
The data describing each character is sent from your CPU to the graphics card every frame - and for every character in the frame. This can amount to significant bandwidth.
The underlying OpenGL implementation will almost certainly have to 'swizzle' the image data in some manner on it's way between CPU and frame-buffer.
Many 3D graphics chips are not designed to draw bitmaps at all. In this case, the OpenGL software driver must wait until the 3D hardware has completely finished drawing before it can get in to splat the pixels directly into the frame buffer. Until the software has finished doing that, the hardware is sitting idle.
Bitmaps and Drawpixels have to be aligned parallel to the edges of the screen, so rotated text is not possible.
Scaling of Bitmaps and Drawpixels is not possible.
There is one significant advantage to Raster fonts - and that is that on Software-only OpenGL implementations, they are likely to be FASTER than the other approaches...the reverse of the situation on 3D hardware.

**Geometric Fonts.**
Draw the characters of the font using geometric primitives - lines, triangles, whatever. The disadvantages of this are:
The number of triangles it takes to draw some characters can be very large - especially if you want them to look good. This can be bad for performance.
Designing fonts is both difficult and costly.
Doing fonts with coloured borders, drop-shadows, etc exacerbates the other two problems significantly.

The advantages are: 
Geometric fonts can be scaled, rotated, twisted, morphed, extruded.
You can use fancy lighting models, environment mapping, texturing, etc.
If used in a 3D world, you can perform collision detection with them.
Geometric fonts scale nicely. They don't exhibit bad aliasing artifacts and they don't get 'fuzzy' as they are enlarged.

**Texture-Mapped Fonts.**
Typically, the entire font is stored in one or two large texture maps and each letter is drawn as a single quadrilateral. The disadvantages are:
The size of the texture map you need may have to be quite large - especially if you need both upper and lower case - and/or if you want to make the font look nice at large point sizes. This is especially a problem on hardware that only supports limited texture map sizes (eg 3Dfx Voodoo's can only render maps up to 256x256)
If you use MIPmapping, then scaling the font makes it look a litte fuzzy. If you don't use MIPmapping, it'll look horribly aliasy.

The advantages are:
Generality - you can use an arbitary full colour image for each letter of the font. 
Texture fonts can be rotated and scaled - although they always look 'flat'.
It's easy to convert other kinds of fonts into texture maps.
You can draw them in the 3D scene and they will be illuminated correctly.
SPEED! Textured fonts require just one quadrilateral to be sent to the hardware for each letter. That's probably an order of magnitude faster than either Raster or Geometric fonts. Since low-end 3D hardware is highly optimised to drawing simple textured polygons, speed is also enhanced because you are 'on the fast path' through the renderer. (CAVEAT: On software-only OpenGL's, textured fonts will be S-L-O-W.

**Links to some Free Font Libraries:**

- [glut](http://www.opengl.org/developers/documentation/glut.html)
- [glTexFont](http://nate.scuzzy.net/programming/gltexfont/)
- [fnt](http://plib.sf.net/fnt)
- [GLTT](http://home.worldnet.fr/~rehel/gltt/gltt.html)
- [freetype](http://www.freetype.org/)

Comment: You did a good job of summarizing the pitfalls that shuttle87 is going to run into. I kind of get the feeling they don't appreciate the headache's they're asking for.

Answer (score 6):

Freetype: http://freetype.sourceforge.net/index2.html
And: http://oglft.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

I use [*FTGL*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/develop), which builds on top of *freetype*.  To create 3D, extruded text, I make these calls:

```
#include <FTGL/ftgl.h>
#include <FTGL/FTFont.h>
...
FTFont* font = new FTExtrudeFont("path_to_Fonts/COOPBL.ttf");
font->Depth(.5);    // Text is half as 'deep' as it is tall
font->FaceSize(1);  // GL unit sized text
...
FTBBox bounds = font->BBox("Text");
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); // Because we're scaling
glPushMatrix();
glScaled(.02,.02,.02);
glTranslated(-(bounds.Upper().X() - bounds.Lower().X())/2.0,yy,zz); // Center the text
font->Render("Text");
glPopMatrix();
glDisable(GL_NORMALIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you QT wich is foundation of KDE or GTk+ for GNOME. Both of them have support for OPENGL and text. With QT you can do advanced graphics(QGraphicsView) , including animation... Take a look at QT Demo Application .

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be NeHe's OpenGL Lesson 14.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=14